# AWS API to Check if Image is used by AutoScalingGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I was wondering if there's anyway to check if an EC2 Image is being used by an AutoScalingGroup via the AWS SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the EC2 Image ID, ie. the AMI id, you could check to see if it is used by an autoscaling group with the following algorithm:

1. Do an [ec2:DescribeAutoScalingGroups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeAutoScalingGroups.html) API call and retrieve the Launch Configuration name from the "LaunchConfigurationName" field.
2. Do an [ec2:DescribeLaunchConfigurations.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeLaunchConfigurations.html) API call. Depending on the SDK you're using, you might be able to filter this API call with the Launch Config name you retrieved in 1. Otherwise you'll get a list of all the Launch Configurations and you'll need to iterate through them and find the correct one from 1.
3. In the Launch Configuration object, there is a field "ImageId". This is what you're looking for.

Depending on the SDK you're using, these API calls may not have the exact same name, and the format of the output fields will vary. You should check the documentation for the relevant SDK for clarification.